# How to take the value from text field and show it on the other text field?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to take the value from text field and show it on the other text field.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class tempretureConverter extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'tempretureConverter_screen';
  @override
  _tempretureConverterState createState() => _tempretureConverterState();
}
class _tempretureConverterState extends State<tempretureConverter> {
  final myControllerCelisius = TextEditingController();
  final myControllerFerhrenhite = TextEditingController();
  String textFieldValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  double celisius, fehrenhite;
  double celisiusCalculation(double c){
    return (c * 9/5) + 32;
  }
  double fehrenhiteCalculation(double f){
    return (f - 32) * 5/9;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child:
                  Image.asset('images/tempreture_converter_icon.png'),
                  height: 100,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Tempreture Converter',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 20
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible( flex: 3,child:TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: myControllerCelisius,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        celisius = value as double;
                        if(celisius != 0){
                          fehrenhiteCalculation(celisius);
                          myControllerFerhrenhite.text;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Celisius',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        )
                    ))),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Flexible( flex: 3,child:TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: myControllerFerhrenhite,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        fehrenhite = value as double;
                        if(fehrenhite != 0){
                          celisiusCalculation(fehrenhite);
                          myControllerCelisius.text;
                        }
                      });
                      },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Fehrenhite',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        )
                    ))),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('Convert', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),),)

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code takes the value from Fahrenheit and changes it to Celsius and vice versa, and for the raised button I will use it later to convert, but first I want to change the values automatically in the text fields then I will use the "converter button".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below lone code u can change some text of a field :

> ```
> _textController.text = value;
> ```

> ```
> // value can be any text in any onChange method
> ```

> ```
> //after it changed and u get value, text of controller with change to it
> ```

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class tempretureConverter extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'tempretureConverter_screen';
  @override
  _tempretureConverterState createState() => _tempretureConverterState();
}
class _tempretureConverterState extends State<tempretureConverter> {
  final myControllerCelisius = TextEditingController();
  final myControllerFerhrenhite = TextEditingController();
  String textFieldValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  double celisius, fehrenhite;
  double celisiusCalculation(double c){
    return (c * 9/5) + 32;
  }
  double fehrenhiteCalculation(double f){
    return (f - 32) * 5/9;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child:
                  Image.asset('images/tempreture_converter_icon.png'),
                  height: 100,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Tempreture Converter',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 20
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible( flex: 3,child:TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: myControllerCelisius,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        celisius = value as double;
                        if(celisius != 0){
                          fehrenhiteCalculation(celisius);
                          myControllerFerhrenhite.text = value; //this line 
                                     //help you to change next textfield
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Celisius',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        )
                    ))),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Flexible( flex: 3,child:TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: myControllerFerhrenhite,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        fehrenhite = value as double;
                        if(fehrenhite != 0){
                          celisiusCalculation(fehrenhite);
                          myControllerCelisius.text;
                        }
                      });
                      },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Fehrenhite',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                        )
                    ))),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('Convert', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),),)

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use a listener, I have read the documentation, but actually I did not understand the use of the listener for example: myControllerCelisius.addListener(() {
      changeFehrnhiteValue();
    });